# Recommendation: Multi-step VS One Page product Builder

Tags: usability, usability-testing, recommendations

**I have a website where the user needs to fill in 4 steps:**

1. Pick a box design
2. Add message
3. Upload 4 photos
4. Pick a gift inside the box

I'm currently using a multistep wizard, **but conversion rate is low**.
People normally will not finish the whole steps.

I'm trying to make everything in one single column, to see if conversion rises.

**My problem comes in the last step, where users can select from +30 gifts to put inside their boxes, so I'm thinking of:**

- A. A modal with the gift selection
- B. A scroll-y with all of the gifts
- C. Dropdowns (less info for gifts)

Which do you think will work best? Any recommendations for this step?

[image]

Comment: Wasnt "picking up a gift" second step in your description in text, you are mentioning now it is last? Could you provide more clear screenshots of each step?

Comment: Hello xul, I corrected the error, the part where it says "Select your gift" will have over 30 gifts to select from (only one gift to be selected). I'm struggling with the cleanest and pro-converting way of showing that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

CR can be low for number of reasons, you should read in analytics (with click Events) or with Mouseflow where your users exactly break.

Gifts can be in modal like shown on this basic wireframe, UX-wise thats in my opinion fair enough.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to keep gift selection outside of your other steps. Would it make more sense to ask the user to choose a gift first, and then choose the packaging and other related stuff?

Or is it because the gifts are dependent on box selections?

In any case, if there are prices attached to the gifts, I'd treat gifts as my primary choice, and the rest could just be a checkout process.

Comment: Without knowing more (as Adnan indicated) it's hard to know your requirements and why the gift selection is last, but I would agree with him; gifts would SEEM to be the primary thing to choose, then figure out how to package them.